# How not to overlap the header from another file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, include

I've made a header jsp file to use other pages.

In the header file, there is a nav bar that sticks to the top(using bootstrap)

When I include the header file at another page, navbar is all good

but contents are overlapped by the nav bar.

Below is the code from another page, and I also attached how it looks.

```
<html>
<%@ include file="../include/header.jsp" %>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</script>
<style>
table { table-layout: fixed; }
table th, table td { overflow: hidden; }
td {
    white-space:pre
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br>
<h2>English lines are under here</h2>
<h5>Just click each cell if you want to modify</h5>
<br>
<table id="btable" class="bg-light table table-hover table-condensed">
<thead>
    <th class= "text-center" width="6%">No</th>
    <th class= "text-center" width="12%">Word</th>
    <th class= "text-center" width="44%">Dialogue</th>
    <th class= "text-center" width="40%">Practice</th>
</thead>
```

The picture is being overlapped by navbar
[image]

Comment: try `.nav{padding-bottom:5rem;}`

Comment: That's because your header has a fixed positioning. You can add a margin or padding with the same height as your header on your container to fix this.